# Stack overflow error in a Leetcode problem 'Inorder Tree Traversal'

Tags: c++, binary-tree, inorder

I am trying to solve Leetcode problem 94 'Binary Tree Inorder Traversal' using Morris Traversal.
I did write a solution to the problem, but on Leetcode it is giving ***AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow*** error. When I run the same code on my local machine it is working fine. Following is the code -

```
vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root)
{
    vector<int> result;
    TreeNode* current = root;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->left != NULL)
        {
            TreeNode* temp = current->left;
            while (temp->right != NULL && temp->right != current)
                temp = temp->right;
            if (temp->right == NULL)
            {
                temp->right = current; /**** Error causing line. ****/
                current = current->left;
                continue;
            }
        }
        result.push_back(current->val);
        current = current->right;
    }
    return result;
}
```

While debugging, I found that the line `temp->right = current` is giving the error (Highlighted in the code above).
To me, the line looks fine but it seems I am missing something here.

Comment: *When I run the same code on my local machine it is working fine* -- Too bad we can't run it, because you didn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you realize that the line `temp->right = current;` is modifying your tree's structure my creating a _cycle_ looping back to an ancestor of the `temp` node?  What this means is: (a) ordinary recursive traversal of the tree will not terminate, and overflow the stack; (b) deletion of the tree is likely to cause the same memory to be released more than once.

Comment: Yes, that is because the Morris traversal method creates a threaded binary tree.